# you must enable mobile hub service before using awsmobile hub cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, aws-cli, amazon-linux

I am creating sample Ionic AWS Starter from in AWS Linux AMI server from [this link](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/tree/master/ionic-angular/official/aws).

I have installed Ionic, cordova, and created project. when I am giving Creating AWS Mobile Hub Project. It was showing below error. Please help me fix below 
mentioned issue.

```
[example-ec2-user@ip-some-ipaddress]: backend awsmobile project creation error

You must enable Mobile Hub service role before using the awsmobile cli
https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home?#/activaterole/
```

Comment: I am facing the above-mentioned issue when I am using "awsmobile init" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an indication that your AWS CLI user does not have permission to perform actions in AWS Mobile Hub. To resolve this, add the managed policy "AWSMobileHub_FullAccess" to your AWS CLI user.

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually caused by the AWS Mobile Hub Service Role is missing in you account.

Could you please go to [AWS IAM console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#/roles), and check if you have a role named: "MobileHub_Service_Role". If the role does not exist, please follow the [link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home?#/activaterole/) to enable AWS Mobile Hub in your account. This action will need administrator permissions. Once you enabled AWS Mobile Hub you will be able to create AWS Mobile Hub project.

If you have already the "MobileHub_Service_Role" and still getting this error, please contact me again.

Sincerely,
Shufan K
AWS Mobile Developer Experience

Comment: What fixed the issue for me was adding the `AWSMobileHub_FullAccess` policy to my admin group. The `MobileHub_Service_Role` policy alone didn't work for me.

Comment: I have "MobileHub_Service_Role" on my account. Still, I am facing the Issue.

Comment: It is working Thank you. The issue is  I have created IAM user and logged in EC2 Instance with that UNAME. I am not enabled "MobileHub_Service_Role"  in that USER. Now it is cleared

Comment: i could only solve this by changing the needed AWS account  in `~/.aws/config` to the default user. I tried adding the correct credentials with `awsmobile configure`, but it always uses the credentials from the default user defined in `~/.aws/config`

Comment: @Shufan I'm facing the same issue (more or less) while all the configurations specified here are set. Could you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927351/im-not-authorized-to-perform-mobilehubgetproject-while-ive-got-the-administr