# I'm not authorized to perform: mobilehub:GetProject while I've got the AdministratorAccess permission

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to setup a Mobile Hub project and according to [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/reference-mobile-hub-project-permissions-model.html), my user on AWS needs to have `AdministratorAccess` permission before it can create a project on Mobile Hub. Now, when I run the following command:

```
$ awsmobile init XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

It prompts an error:

```
failed to link to backend awsmobile project with id = XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

{ UnauthorizedException: Sorry, but you do not have permission for this operation. For help, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/managed-policies.html. Details = User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/XXXXXX is not authorized to perform: mobilehub:GetProject on resource: arn:aws:mobilehub:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:project/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX with an explicit deny
    at Object.extractError (/usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)
    at Request.extractError (/usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:52:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/awsmobile-cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
  message: 'Sorry, but you do not have permission for this operation. For help, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/managed-policies.html. Details = User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/XXXXXX is not authorized to perform: mobilehub:GetProject on resource: arn:aws:mobilehub:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:project/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX with an explicit deny',
  code: 'UnauthorizedException',
  time: 2018-04-19T17:39:47.179Z,
  requestId: 'a737c3c5-43f8-11e8-ad18-c3e47c13a2c2',
  statusCode: 401,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 75.21814774329248 }

You must enable Mobile Hub service role before using the awsmobile cli
https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home?#/activaterole/
```

The problem is that my user has got `AdministratorAccess` permission. Yet I'm unable to initialize a Mobile Hub project.

One other thing, when I go to my user's `Access Advisor` page, I can see the `AWSMobileHub_FullAccess` policy for the service `AWS Mobile Hub` in the list.

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like there is a Deny statement in your user's permission. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Can you please help me find the Deny statement? Should I look for it in my user account? In the group that I belong to? How can I find this deny statement? All I can see is a list of policies.

Comment: When you go to the IAM user console and select your user, you will find a list of policies or groups that are attached to your user. Please check if any of them has a Deny statement.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR I'm not sure if it helps or not but I've updated the question. Also, the permissions page simply has `ForceMFA`, `AdministratorAccess`, and `AWSDataPipeline_FullAccess`. There's no Deny statement as far as I can see.

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR Thanks, I've found the issue. As you've mentioned it was a hidden deny within the custom policy. Thanks

Comment: Cool, I will type that as answer to close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, it looks like there is a Deny statement in your user's permission. When you go to the IAM user console and select your user, you will find a list of policies or groups that are attached to your user. Please check if any of them has a Deny statement.

Comment: Did anyone find this to be the solution to their problem? I would curious to know more details. I added Admin Permissions to my user, but still get the denial message, same for our account owner.